# How to show a popup(see image) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Just starting out with iOS developing in Swift so I'm not certain how to call this thing.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a choice like the image below.

What is it called and where do I start?

[image: Choice popup or so?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/) is what you are searching for.

Be careful because it's deprecated since iOS 8 but the reference links to the replacement as well.

> in iOS 8 and later, instead use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController) with a [preferredStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertController/preferredStyle) of [UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet).